# SQL script using Q119, Q318 to Q418 references to measures. Any suggested code improvement

Tags: sql, variables, alias

The problem is manually updating the script references Q119 etc to change to the next quarter.

I'm work with script using Q418, Q119 as references to quarter measures but this means each new quarter I have to manually change Q119 to Q219, Q418 to Q119, Q318 to Q418 and so forth.  Any suggestions for a better process.

I've tried with looping variables but didn't work out.

```
SELECT S.REV, S.QUARTER
FROM SALES S
WHERE S.QUARTER IN('Q119','Q418')
```

I expect to see the following:

```
REV   QUARTER
100   Q119
75    Q418
```

- The real data I'm working with is much more complex but for the purpose of this question I want to keep it basic.
- Ideally I would like to see the script take the current quarter as a parameter and based on this derive the previous 8 quarters and include them in the result.

Comment: What DB is this? Is there any other kind of date in the sales table, relating to the exact date of sale?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the quarters using a recursive CTE.  For instance:

```
with qs as (
      select concat('Q', datename(quarter, getdate()), year(getdate()) % 100) as qy,1 as lev
      union all
      select concat('Q', datename(quarter, dateadd(quarter, - lev, getdate())), year(dateadd(quarter, - lev, getdate())) % 100) as qy, lev + 1
      from qs
      where lev < 8
     )
select s.rev, s.quarter
from sales s
where s.quarter in (select q from qs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of quarters using a list of numbers:

The first step would be to establish a start date (which is the first of a quarter), for this I have assumed a year and quarter parameter, but realistically this could be any input:

e.g.

```
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 2,
        @Year INT = 2019

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@year, (@Quarter * 3) - 2, 1);
```

Wil return

```
2019-04-01
```

Then using a numbered list (from 0-7) you can deduct a quarter at a time from this start date, and format the date as you please:

```
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 2,
        @Year INT = 2019

SELECT Code = CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, QuarterStart), FORMAT(QuarterStart, 'yy')),
        QuarterStart
FROM (  SELECT QuarterStart = DATEADD(QUARTER, - n.Number, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, (@Quarter * 3) - 2, 1))
        FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(2),(4),(5),(6),(7)) n (Number)
    ) q;
```

Will return

```
Code    QuarterStart
--------------------------
Q219    2019-04-01
Q119    2019-01-01
Q418    2018-10-01
Q418    2018-10-01
Q218    2018-04-01
Q118    2018-01-01
Q417    2017-10-01
Q317    2017-07-01
```

If you need to extend this beyond 8 quarters, you can either add more rows to the table value constructor, or you could create a numbers table. More on that here: [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

If you need to incorporate this in your main query you can simply embed it:

```
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 2,
        @Year INT = 2019;

SELECT  S.REV, S.QUARTER
FROM    SALES S
WHERE   EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM (SELECT QuarterStart = DATEADD(QUARTER, - n.Number, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, (@Quarter * 3) - 2, 1))
                    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(2),(4),(5),(6),(7)) n (Number)) q
            WHERE   s.QUARTER = CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, QuarterStart), FORMAT(QuarterStart, 'yy'))
        )
```

Or you could use a table variable, if you need to re-use the quarters throughout a query:

```
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 2,
        @Year INT = 2019;

DECLARE @Quarter TABLE (QuarterCode CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @Quarter (QuarterCode)
SELECT  CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, QuarterStart), FORMAT(QuarterStart, 'yy'))
FROM (  SELECT QuarterStart = DATEADD(QUARTER, - n.Number, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, (@Quarter * 3) - 2, 1))
        FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(2),(4),(5),(6),(7)) n (Number)
    ) q;

SELECT S.REV, S.QUARTER
FROM SALES S
WHERE S.QUARTER IN (SELECT QuarterCode FROM @Quarter);
```